# Creating an rpm package that untars a file

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I would like to create a rpm package that does the following:

When setup:

1. copies a script across into the rpm
2. untars a file into the rpm

When run:

1. runs `script.sh`
2. runs `install` file that is extracted into the rpm

When the user runs the rpm it should execute 2 and 3 because the files already exist in the rpm.

I know how to do the setup stuff, the *.spec file is:

```
%description
# lets skip this for now

%prep
# lets skip this for now

%build
# lets skip this for now

%install
cd ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
cp -v /home/methuselah/script.sh ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
tar xvpf /home/methuselah/bin.tar
chmod 775 -R ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/*

%files
/*

%changelog
* Tue Jan 28 2014 Pavel Šimerda  - 3.0.9-14
- Resolves: #1052814 - rsync command is terminated with SIGSEGV
- Resolves: #1052814 - add missing patch file
```

I'm not sure where to put the actual installation steps that run when the rpm is executed.

Comment: I think you should present your actual use case, because what you're asking to do is **generally a bad idea** and goes against what RPM is there for. Once you untar a file, let's say `/etc/randomfile`, how is the user supposed to know where it came from? SAs are trained to check the RPM database - it's not in there, because you randomly dropped it in. Now the admin needs to track it down and make sure there hasn't been some kind of breach, etc.

Answer (score 3):

the `%install` section is there to **install** the files during the **rpm build** process in the **rpm build root**. This part is not run during installation on the target machine. That is the confusing part of `spec` files.

During the building of the `rpm` (in this order):

- %prep
- %build
- %install
- %check

during the installation of the `rpm` (in this order):

- %pre
- (real installation: files from `%files` section are installed)
- %post

NOTE: [this page on the full rpm scripts order](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/)

some more remarks:

- two `rpm`s cannot own the same file/folder, so make sure you don't package `/home`, `/usr` or something like that (when specifying `/*` under `%files` you are packaging the whole tree)
- don't package files in the `/home` directory of a user. Packages are installed system-wide, so package only files in generic directories like `/etc` , `/usr`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to put your files (script.sh and bin.tar) under the "%files" section and leave all installation with %install.

Take a look [here](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html) and maybe [here](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/) for more information.

> I'm not sure where to put the actual installation steps that run when the rpm is executed.

I think this [link](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/05/how-to-execute-script-at-pre-post-preun-postun-spec-file-rpm.html) can help you.

Comment: while helpfull, if possible at least describe what each link is supposed to help the user with, so he doesn't need to open them all to see what they are about.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Yes, you're right! I wanted to give a quick answer before editing my own answer with more info. But your answer nails it. :-)